Efficiently list distinct folders
I need to get a list of distinct folder names from my Azure data lake via Synapse Serverless SQL.
My structure is device/message/yyyy/mm/dd/xyz.parquet.
I have illustrated an example that works below:
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.filepath(1) AS deviceid
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/xyzdatalakestoragegen2filesystem/*/*/*/*/*/*',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) as r

The problem is that this scans my entire data lake to return the distinct list - which is of course extremely inefficient. At the same time I do not have explicit knowledge of e.g. 'specific existing paths/files' in the data lake up front - the query needs to work across various data lakes of this structure.
Any tricks to make this more efficient, yet still use TSQL?

Not sure it's possible, but you should be able to write a python or ps script that scans your lakes and stores the directories into some table for further sql processing

Agree, I was just hoping to find a way to do this 'on the fly'. My goal is to create a query-based table that will list my folders so that I can use them as slicers to allow end users in Power BI to dynamically select which tables from the data lake to visualize. The work flow does not easily entail running an ad hoc Python script to perform the mapping on the side - at least a lot of the 'simplicity' is then lost.
